# No available checkers with Syntastic

Tags: vim, path, pylint, syntastic

I've installed Syntastic with Pathogen, and tried just about all I can think of to get Syntastic to recognize my pylint checker.

Pylint checker is installed here

```
/home/myself/.local/bin/pylint
```

I echoed my path and

```
/home/myself/.local/bin
```

is indeed in the $PATH variable.

My .vimrc looks like this

```
set tabstop=4

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive',
                       \ 'active_filetypes': ['python'],
                       \ 'passive_filetypes': ['perl'] }
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint', 'python']
```

and yet when I run the command

```
SyntasticInfo
```

inside vim, I still see

```
Syntastic: passive mode enabled
Syntastic version: 3.4.0-79
Info for filetype:
Available checker(s):
Currently enabled checker(s):
```

Spent a good while searching google for this, does anyone have a clue as to what I have forgotten?

EDIT/ANSWER:
In case anyone else needs help with something like this, doing

```
:setfiletype python
```

appeared to get things right.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues with the filetype plugins, weirdly but this helped:

```
filetype off " <<< this line
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```